# Is there a way to get the constructor name of a function expression?

Tags: javascript

I noticed in my code that I cannot get the name of the constructor when I use a function expression.

```
var X = function () { /* some code*/ };
var foo = new X();
console.log(foo.constructor.name); // ""
```

but if I use a function declaration I can

```
function X() {/*some code*/}
var foo = new X();
console.log(foo.constructor.name); //"X"
```

Is there a way to get the name of the constructor when I use a function expression? Perhaps some hack?

Comment: If it has no name, what were you hoping it would give? And why do you need it in the first place?

Comment: it has a name, it's anonymous

Comment: Should I have added an LOL at the end.

Comment: You can't get the name of an annonymous function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because I am working on a graph that maps constructor functions names from a rendering engine. I was noticing that chrome dev tools have access to the name and was wondering if I could as well. You can laugh but it is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't gets its name if you don't name it.

Either use `function X() { }`, or accept that you can't assign a name to it.

You can freely mix the syntaxes

```
var Y = function X() { };
(new Y).constructor.name; // "X"
```

But this isn't supported in some older browsers (specific versions of IE) and has *no* benefits over simply using `function X() { }`.

Comment: OK I thought so which makes sense but I just noticed that Chrome console had access to the variable name so I thought maybe there was an API or hack I could use. thanks

Comment: What about when you have `var x = y = z = function () {}`?

Comment: Note that the *name* property of [*Function* objects](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5) is not a standard feature of ECMAScript, it just happens to be implemented by current browsers.

Answer (score 2):

When you use function expression, `var Func = function() {...}`. The function is assigned to the `Func` variable as an object reference (functions are objects as well). So, when you use `new Func()` to instantiate an instance, it is actually something like `new (function() {...})`, an **amounymous** constructor. There's nothing to do with the variable indicator. That's why you can't get the variable name.

Alternatively, you can use a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/), which might be a little bit different though.

```
var X = function Func() { /* some code*/ };
var foo = new X();
console.log(foo.constructor.name); // "Func"
```

This is very commonly used in OOP style JS. Another example:

```
function Obj() {...}
Obj.prototype.method = function _method() { ... };
```

One of advantages to do so is that, when you debug your code, at break points you could see the function name in call stack, rather than "anounymous". Here's an example from kangax's article. Please notice the difference I highlighted.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah I am familiar with doing that for debugging and looking at the call stack, it is very helpful. I mentioned it because I noticed Chrome console had access to it but I guess that's all internal. Thanks. I was pretty sure there was no API I could access.

Comment: @EdgarMartinez Updated my answer about the reason. Help that would help for you :)